# python: taking data from csv returns each character as a separate string

Tags: python, database, csv

basically, I am using a csv file to store data for an inventory for a game. in the csv file, when it is generated, it appears in the csv file as follows.

[image]

it is then called with the following code:

```py
def tileResource():
    global allItems
    global playerEnergy

    if currentTile == "grass":
        currentTileResources = ["crickits","strawberries"]
    if currentTile == "sand":
        currentTileResources = ["sand","cactus"]
    if currentTile == "wasteland":
        currentTileResources = ["scrap"]
    if currentTile == "hills":
        currentTileResources = ["herbs","blackberries"]
    if currentTile == "lake":
        currentTileResources = ["water"]
    if currentTile == "mountain":                                                                                                                                                
        currentTileResources = ["stone","ironore"]
    if currentTile == "forest":
        currentTileResources = ["wood","vine","apple"]

    storeData = []
    list2 = []
    list2T="hello"
    resource = random.choice(currentTileResources)
    msgbox(resource,"resource found")
    playerEnergy - 2
    length = 0
    count = 0

    with open('inventory.csv', 'r', newline='') as newfile1:
        for line in newfile1:
            list1 = []
            list1 = line

            number = 0

            woodResource = []
            stoneResource = []
            scrapResource = []
            ironoreResource = []
            sandResource = []
            waterResource = []
            vineResource = []
            strawberriesResource = []
            blackberriesResource = [] 
            herbsResource = []
            applesResource = []
            crickitsResource = []
            cactusResource = []



            if resource == "wood":
                if "A" in list1:
                    number = int(list1[2])
                    number = number+1
                list2 = ["A","wood",number]

            elif resource == "stone":
                if "B"in list1:
                    number = int(list1[2])
                    number = number+1
                list2 = ["B","stone",number]

            elif resource == "scrap":
                if "C"in list1:
                    number = int(list1[2])
                    number = number+1
                list2 = ["C","scrap",number]

            elif resource == "ironore":
                if "D" in list1:
                    number = int(list1[2])
                    number = number+1
                list2 = ["D","ironore",number]

    #code continues for rest of items

    with open('inventory.csv', 'w', newline='') as newfile1:
        list1 = []
        data=csv.writer(newfile1)
        # a loop writes data to the file as separate lists using:
        data.writerow(storeData)
```

however, when it is ran, and puts the data back into the file, it turns into the following:

"L","1","w","o","o","d","0" 
"L","2","s","t","o","n","e","0"

 and so on.

anyone have any ideas on what is going wrong, or how to adapt and fix the output? all of this is handles inside the scripts (no user textual input).I need the 3 items to be separate in a list and to go back into the csv so i can increase the "0"'s.

Comment: `storeData` is an empty list, your code is not correct

Comment: yeah, I changed the code  a bit to try to fix the error. the storeData actually had the rest of the list in it at one point. that was how it was put back in the csv file

Comment: can you provide the output of `print(storeData)`?

Comment: it would be the values of all previous lists, basically the csv file prior to the implementation of the code, separated into 1 list per line. with literally 1 number changed. basically a list of lists

Comment: please provide one sample